# Why is ServerXMLHTTP send method returning an Automation Error?

Tags: html, xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am wondering if someone can reproduce this on their system: the function shown below works fine on Windows 7 running Office 2013, but it generates an "Automation Error" at `XMLhttp.send` on another system running Windows 7 and Office 2010. I should perhaps also mention that the first system has IE 11 while the second one (where I get the Automation Error) has IE 8. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
Public Function getWiki(ByVal name As String) As String
  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
  XMLhttp.setTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
  XMLhttp.Open "GET", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & name, False
  XMLhttp.send

  If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
    getWiki = XMLhttp.responseText
  Else
    getWiki = ""
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Are the Excel VBA references and IE permissions (IE-Tools-Internet Options-Advanced) set the same on the two systems?

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes they appear to be the same besides the different versions of object libraries between office 2013 and 2010